# Flume- Error Log while using FileChannel

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cdh4, apache-flume

I am using Flume flume-ng-1.5.0 ( with CDH 5.4)  to collect logs from many Servers and Sink to HDFS
Here is my configuration :

```
#Define Source , Sinks, Channel
collector.sources = avro
collector.sinks = HadoopOut
collector.channels = fileChannel


# Define Scribe Interface
collector.sources.avro.type = avro
collector.sources.avro.bind = 0.0.0.0
collector.sources.avro.port = 1463
collector.sources.avro.threads = 5
collector.sources.avro.channels = fileChannel



collector.channels.fileChannel.type = file
collector.channels.fileChannel.checkpointDir = /channel/flume/collector/checkpoint
collector.channels.fileChannel.dataDirs = /channel/flume/collector/data
#collector.channels.fileChannel.transactionCapacity = 100000
#collector.channels.fileChannel.capacity = 1000000000

#Describe Haoop Out
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.type = hdfs
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.channel = fileChannel
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.path = /logfarm/%{game_studio}/%{product_code}/%Y-%m-%d/%{category}
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.filePrefix = %{category}-%Y-%m-%d
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.inUseSuffix = _current
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

#Max File size = 10 MB
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.round = true
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.roundValue = 10
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.rollSize = 10000000
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.rollCount = 0
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.rollInterval = 600
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.maxOpenFiles = 4096
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.timeZone = Asia/Saigon
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.threadsPoolSize = 50
collector.sinks.HadoopOut.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
```

The directories : /channel/flume/collector/checkpoint, /channel/flume/collector/data is blank and own by user flume

But I have the weird exception :

```
2015-05-08 18:31:34,290 ERROR org.apache.flume.SinkRunner: Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed [channel=fileChannel]. Due to java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.createTransaction(FileChannel.java:340)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicChannelSemantics.getTransaction(BasicChannelSemantics.java:122)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:368)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:827)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readLong(RandomAccessFile.java:860)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.get(EventQueueBackingStoreFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.Log.replay(Log.java:426)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.file.FileChannel.start(FileChannel.java:290)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
```

I want any expert help me to fix it.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar error related to the Flume channel.
I got it fixed when I deleted/moved both data and checkpoint directories.

In your case:

/channel/flume/collector/checkpoint, /channel/flume/collector/data

Make sure the directory "/channel/flume/collector/" is clean and empty. 
re-running the flume job should create both "checkpoint" and "data" directories.

It is always safe to move the directories and save it somewhere you like as a future reference of logs. I was successful in doing this on both CDH 5.4 (flume 1.5) as well as CDh 5.5 (flume 1.6). Most of exceptions regarding the channel close should be fixed by this.

For reference:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flume-user/201309.mbox/%3CCAC4PaS8LzX7QbDZBMV=Nw94xeeocd=m+vbNrL6DhXOe+t-gQ5Q@mail.gmail.com%3E

I believe apache.org is still working on this Issue
Check this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2282

Hope it helps!!